# How to control Windows' Programs and Features using Python

Tags: python, windows

There is Programs and Features in Windows Control Panel.

I'd like to control it like Uninstall and Change using Python.

[image]

How should I achieve this?

I couldn't find any meaningful material.

Comment: Have you found an API for other languages?

Comment: No, I'm only using Python for this. Especially PyQt.

Comment: I wasn't asking if you wanted to use it, but Python is not a first-class language in the Windows environment, so you may not have a chance. Also, if you don't even find one for C, C++ or one of the .Net languages, then maybe there is no API.

Comment: Oops! With Python, even the registry could be controlled using the `winreg` module. So, I thought there was a way I couldn't find it. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 3 ways to do this.

**A)** Read the uninstall entries yourself from the registry. There are 4 locations, HKCU/HKLM, 32&64-bit. `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` and enumerate the subkeys.

**B)** Using the shell interfaces. When you have the `IShellFolder` for the Programs and Features you can get the `IContextMenu` and execute command. I don't recommend this because Programs and Features is going away, everything is being moved to the Settings app.

**C)** [UIAutomation](https://pypi.org/project/uiautomation/). Not recommended for the same reason as B and it can also be fragile.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll check the A method.